# How to stop the loading flicker when adding a large amount of MKOverlays to a map

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit

I [have an app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id448049851?mt=8) that displays cycle paths in the UK on a map:

I found, for performance reasons, I had to split up the fetching of the map data into tiles.  I fetch a tile at a time using an NSOperationQueue, and display it on the map.  This has greatly improved the responsiveness however, its introduced another issue where the map sometimes flickers each time a add a set of overlays to it.

- An example of this happening can be seen in a [screen recording I made](http://youtu.be/7ZcS6RGs9Is) on the Simulator:
- [Another example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J73tnd6a4OM&feature=youtu.be) just using some random lines instead of my cycle paths.

Im not doing anything too out of the ordinary in the code.

```
[self.mapView addOverlays:overlays];  // On the main thread
```

...

```
if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[RSPathOverlay class]])
{
    RSPathOverlay* pathOverlay = (RSPathOverlay*) overlay;

    MKPolylineView* view = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

    view.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    view.lineWidth = 4.3;

    return view;
}
```

- What is causing the flicker to sometimes occur?
- How can I reduce / remove the flicker?

I have asked [this question on the dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/794289#794289), although there were some responses with similar issues, a good solution has not been found.

Answer (score 0):

I have filled a bug report with that issue. It only happens in IOS 6 and not in IOS 5.

Comment: I find its worse on iOS 6, iOS 5 there is still a flicker in some conditions.  Did you find any ways to reduce the flicker?

Comment: Hi Robert. No I haven't found any way to reduce the flicker.

Comment: Did Apple respond to this bug report?

Comment: I have never been responded by Apple on any bug report.